# What's the added benefit of retain/autoreleasing an already retained property?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, retain, autorelease

At a project I'm currently working on I'm working through code of my predecessors. One of the things I encounter here and there are getters like this:

```
- (NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    return [[userInfo retain] autorelease]; 
}
```

Obviously userInfo is already retained by the class, what I don't get is: What's the added value of retain-autoreleasing this object? What would be the difference with this method:

```
- (NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    return userInfo;
}
```

Cheers,
EP.

Comment: Maybe he/she just didn't understand memory management at the time? There could be a very good reason for it, maybe it "fixed" an intermittant bug or related issue. People have all sorts of reasons for the code they write, and some of the time it doesn't even make sense to them when they revisit it ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine this:

```
id x = [[A alloc] init];
NSDictionary *userInfo = [x userInfo];
[x release];
// Do something with userInfo ...
// Would fail if the getter did not retain/autorelease.
```

This would fail if the getter did not do the retain/autorelease thing because `userInfo` would get deallocated when `x` gets deallocated.

Answer (score 3):

It allows the result returned to persist for the entirety of the current call stack even if the owning object is deallocated in the interim. The custom in Cocoa is that anything that is returned by a getter without an owning reference (ie, any getter without 'new', 'alloc', 'retain' or 'create' in the name) will last for at least as long as the enclosing autorelease pool.

For example:

```
Object1 *object1 = [[Object1 alloc] init];
ResultObject *result = [object1 someResult];
[object1 release];

// result is still valid here, even though object1 was released
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out the release of object1 while still having a retain count on the someResult. The answer mark goes to Ole though, for using the same terminology as the answer. Thanks Tommy!

Comment: Oh well; I was hoping that answering first, more generally and with a comment on the reason why someone might Legitimately expect the result still to be valid would buy me some extra credit, but having helped is plenty enough.